# Avro unions containing multiple arrays

Tags: c++, avro

I'm attempting to use the C++ avro library in our software and I've hit a significant snag. I have a "Value" class that wraps a range of types, and I want to use avro to read/write it. This includes not only simple types, but std::vectors of types, arbitrary classes and more.

I'm trying to specify an avro schema for my "Value" class. In my example I've limited it to it to empty, int, long, arrays of ints and arrays of long.

My schema is a record with two fields, one that identifies the contained type, and a union to hold the contained object. The schema I have for it is the following...

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Value",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "ilk",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "contents",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "boolean",
                "int",
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": "int"
                },
                "long",
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": "long"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't specify the JSON, but construct an avro C++ schema hierarchy which printed out the above. Validating that schema hierarchy fails though. Sniffing through the C++ code it stops you having more than one array or map in the union, even if the types in the array or map are different.

Is this actually a part of the avro standard or is it a bug in the C++ implementation? I get that specifying the same type twice is a silly thing to do, but I would not have thought that arrays and maps with different contained types would be allowed.

Answer (score 2):

I actually don't think this is what you want todo. What you want todo is create an array that have different types. Like this.

```
{
  "namespace": "example.avro",
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Example",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "values",
      "type":
      {
        "type": "array",
        "items": ["int", "string"]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This will create an array that can have two simple types. Either "int" or "string". You can pop any complex type in there.

Comment: That can't work with our internal type system, I got around it by wrapping each array type in a dummy record.

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer in the standard. You can't have more than one array or map inside a union.

Sounds somewhat lame to me, so I'll have to find a dirty work around.